# How to use existing values in "HTML" config using Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Since Sencha Touch has all the interface elements, I decided to use it. Can someone tell me how to integrate the existing value in an items "HTML" config?

Codes are showing below:

### I've got a form1

```
var form1 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id: 'form1',
    standardSubmit : false,
    scroll:'vertical',
    dockedItems: [
        form1topToolBar
    ],
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'form1One',
            label: 'Name'
        }
    ]    
});
```

### I've also got a form2

```
var form2 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id: 'form2',
    standardSubmit : false,
    scroll:'vertical',
    dockedItems: [
        form2topToolBar
    ],
    items: [
        {
            html: [
                '<table class="outputTable">',
                '<tr>',
                '<td>form1.getValues().form1One</td>',  <-------- Here is the value that I want. 
                '</tr>',
                '</table>'
            ]
        }
    ]    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are trying to update the `<td>` element when the user changes values. Here is the code to do that:

```
    var form1 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        id: 'form1',
        standardSubmit : false,
        scroll:'vertical',
        dockedItems: [
            form1topToolBar
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'form1One',
                label: 'Name',
                listeners: {
                    'change' : {
                        fn : function (field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                            var myUpdatedText;  // example of calculated text
                            myUpdatedText = form1.getValues().form1One;
                            myUpdatedText += form2.getValues().form2Two;
                            Ext.getCmp('form2ChangingField').update({
                                updatedText : myUpdatedText
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]    
    });       

    // other code here... then definition of form2 starts here

    var form2 = new Ext.form.FormPane({
        id: 'form2',
        standardSubmit : false,
        scroll:'vertical',
        dockedItems: [
            form2topToolBar
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'form2Two'
            },
            {
                id: 'form2ChangingField',
                tpl: new Ext.Template('<table class="outputTable">'+
                                      '<tr>'+
                                      '<td>{updatedText}</td>'+
                                      '</tr>'+
                                      '</table>'
                );
            }
        ]
    });
```

Go [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Template) to learn more about templates.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the quick response! But seems it's not working, I tried it, but the result is undefined?

Comment: most likely, it's because the field in form1 that contains the name "form1One" does not have a value. I will update my answer.

Comment: I can use the value in some other places, but not in this one?

Comment: It depends on when you are defining form2. If you are defining it before form1 gets updated with values, then the value will not be available. Most likely, you are using it in other places after it has received a value from the user.

Comment: by the way, are you trying to update form2's html dynamically based on the value of form1's "form1One" field?

Comment: form1 was defined before form2 and I tried to test with the given initial value, It did work!! But when I change to use the form1.getValues().form1One, it just said "undifined". Actually I am working on updating form2's html dynamically based on the value of form1's "form1One" field. Any point I missed?

Comment: I have updated the answer to update it dynamically... you will notice that the field in form1 now has a 'change' handler... when the user changes values of that field, form2's 'changing field' will have its Ext.Template updated with just the data needed. :)

Comment: oops... had to update a quick typo... I using 'grid2' instead of 'form2' ;)

Comment: Thanks for you help Ryan, actually I am using some similar method to do the function I need, and thought the config of "html" might be easier to manipulate. However, your method seems exactly what I need, you are not only solving the question I asked, you answered further more. Appreciate again!!

Comment: By the way, just want to perform some calculations in the template similar to {[values.form1One*values.form1One]} in XTemplate. Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: Personally, when I've used XTemplate, it was to generate XML and I never tried that out personally. However, just keep in mind that when you are calling `update`, you are passing in data that will fill in `{...}`. Therefore, you can call `update({form1One:value.form1One^form1One})`.

Comment: Ryan, what if I need to update the value in the <td> tag which is calculated by two variables? for example: {[values.form1One*values.form1Two]}

Comment: So, when you call `update({form1One:...});`, just replace the `...` by any calculation you need to do. So anything that you have at your disposal in the 'change' event handler you can use to produce the stuff in `...`. You can even put a variable name in place of `...` and do some stuff in the change event, then assign to the variable, then put the variable name as the `...` :)

Comment: I edited the answer to be more generic. There were  a couple of changes: 1.) I added a textfield to form2, 2.) I changed the 'change' event handler to calculate the text that will be used to update the `<td>`, 3.) I changed the template of the `<td>` to now use `{updatedText}` rather than `{form1One}` for clarity :)